# How to prevent users from accessing Visual basic Editor

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365, vba

I want to prevent users from accessing the Visual Basic Editor in any of the application  of Microsoft Office package. Is there any way of doing this by changing any settings in registry or any application specific setting?

I've gone through the various similar kind of questions on SO and other knowledge banks as well but never found any satisfactory answer. Most of the answers I got to were like -"Protect your project", "Disable Alt+F11 for your project" and all but I don't think I can disallow access to the VBE this way.

Please share if have any solution to this problem? I highly appreciate any help!!
Thanks.

Comment: Seen this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281954

Comment: @JamesHunt: thanks a lot for the link... Method 5 is exactly the way I was looking for! Please extend the words and move the comment to answer, I will mark that as answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most versions of Office, VB can be disabled as an additional option at install. With others a Microsoft-authored tool needs to be used.

Check this Knowledge Base link for details: [Microsoft KnowledgeBase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281954)